# In Singapore, can I use MediShield Life together with private insurance to cover co-insurance parts of both?

Tags: insurance, singapore

With the new mandatory MediShield Life insurance policy, every citizen and PR in Singapore is now covered for basic hospitalization in governmental hospitals.

I also have a private insurance, courtesy of my employer, which can cover up to 70-85% of private hospital's bill (can't cancel out of it and they would charge me for it regardless).

Does anyone know whether I would be able to utilize MediShield to cover the rest of the bill, similar to how I could use MediSave before that?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, spoke to insurance agents and they told me you can't; has to be one or the other :/

They could not provide any proof though, so I guess I will just have to wait and see